# using Serenity-js framework ,how to locate a shadow element whose parent has an id which is a normal DOM

Tags: element, shadow, serenity-js

please tell me how i can locate an element in the below form using serenity-js Target.

Below is my Dom to the page i am trying to automate.
[image]
so here its a dropdown which you can see as  which has id="splc" which is a normal DOM .. but the content inside that dropdown are all shadow elements. 
my requirement is to access the content in dropdown.

Now i am not able to even click on the dropdown by normal xpath on px-component tag ( which is normal DOM) .
Inside that px component tag I can see that it has a shadow element #label which is exact element i need to click. 
Problem is in my html page , all the dropdown has the same #label as the shadow element and their parent is a normal xpath with unique id.

When i use the Jquery on the chrome console

```
$("html #splc /deep/ div#label").click()
```

i can click the desired dropdown.

But how can i do the same with serenity-js frame work. 
i want to do the below functionality that i have in protractor using SERENITY-JS concept .

```
static dropdown = element(by.id("splc")).element(by.deepCss("#label"));
```

Since serenity-js expects a target always since the Task needs that in activity. How can do the same ?
please help me.

Comment: I am unsure of how to answer this question. Have you tried your solution using `element(by.id("splc")).element(by.deepCss("#label"));`? Or are you asking advice for a line of code you haven't tried out yet? If you have tried it out, what does the error message look like?

Comment: Hi , 
i tried using the same but since its a ElementFinder and Serenity-js expects Target for the Actor to perform a Activity.

Comment: I need the solution as  how i can use the same concept using serenityis concept.

Comment: So really a serenityJS question. Possibly remove the Protractor tag? I understand that there are parallel ideas with Protractor; however, the question is not about Protractor.

Comment: yes thank u cnishina . i have editted. I need help with serenity-js. To implement the above mentioned concept already present with protractor , with serenity-js

Answer (score 0):

From [what I can see](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/15776b8aef301e3c0a3b1835df1a876414b2de14/lib/locators.ts#L488), `by.deepCss` is nothing more than a wrapper around `by.css`:

```
deepCss(selector: string): Locator {
  return By.css('* /deep/ ' + selector);
};
```

If that's the case, then the following:

```
element(by.id("splc")).element(by.deepCss("#label"))
```

could be represented as:

```
element(by.css("#splc /deep/ #label"))
```

as per your jQuery example.

Now, if the above works, you should be able to define a `Target` as follows:

```
const Dropdown = Target.the('Dropdown').located(by.css("#splc /deep/ #label"))
```

Hope this helps!

Jan